# Button to generate a report not working

Tags: user-interface

I'm trying to create a Button that - when pressed - creates a report using a template. Here is a minimal example:

```
Button["Test",
    GenerateDocument[
        "ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb", <|"author" -> "Henry Jones"|>
    ]
]
```

This creates the Button, but when clicked I get an error "Could not process unknown packet "1"." (or with another number there).

Trying the raw action:

```
GenerateDocument[
    "ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb", <|"author" -> "Henry Jones"|>
]
```

just works fine and opens the generated report as expected.

What's going wrong with the Button action? I've tried `Button` with `CreateNotebook[]` as action, and that works fine, so in principle Buttons *can* open new notebooks, just not in combination with `GenerateDocument` it seems.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the option `Method -> "Queued"`:

```
Button["Test", 
 GenerateDocument["ExampleData/BasicTemplate.nb", <|"author" -> "Henry Jones"|>], 
 Method -> "Queued"]
```

Comment: Incredibly fast and correct answer. Thanks!